# Python Date Conversion reading January date as a November Date

Tags: python

```
152008
2008-01-05 00:00:00
152008
2008-01-05 00:00:00
162008
2008-01-06 00:00:00
162008
2008-01-06 00:00:00
162008
2008-01-06 00:00:00
162008
2008-01-06 00:00:00
1122008
2008-11-02 00:00:00
1122008
2008-11-02 00:00:00
1122008
2008-11-02 00:00:00
1122008
2008-11-02 00:00:00
1132008
2008-11-03 00:00:00
1132008
2008-11-03 00:00:00
1132008
2008-11-03 00:00:00
1132008
2008-11-03 00:00:00
1202008
2008-01-20 00:00:00
```

The strings above are being converted to the dates below them. These are all dates for the month of January. Some of them are being converted to November dates. Any Help?

This how Im currently converting the Dates

```
for i in old_games["Date"]:
    if len(str(i)) <= 4 and i > 900:
        i = str(i) + "2007"
        print(i)
        print(datetime.strptime(str(i), "%m%d%Y"))
    elif len(str(i)) <= 3 and i < 900 and not 109 < i < 120:
        i = str(i) + "2008"
        print(i)
        print(datetime.strptime(str(i), "%m%d%Y"))
```

`1132008` - Should be `1/13/2008`

`2008-11-03 00:00:00` - Actual Output

Comment: Welcome to SO please provide the code producing these results so we can further assist.

Comment: Also how would a 2 digit month work? Or a 1 digit day and a 2 digit month? Seems right now you have `MDDYYYY` But what about `MMDYYYY` etc... For instance your example `1132008` could be `1/13/2008` or `11/3/2008`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. For a question like this, please create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

you need to zero pad the numbers for the month and or day. see the documentation for %m and %d

see docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)
note the change from 1132008 in your code to '01132008'

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime('01132008',"%m%d%Y").date(),"%Y/%m/%d")
```

returns '2008/01/13'

or changing to month/date/year:

```
   datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime('01132008', "%m%d%Y").date(), "%m/%d/%Y")
```

returns '01/13/2008'

from datetime import datetime

```
for i in [152008,152008,162008,162008,162008,162008,1122008,1122008,1122008,1122008,1132008,1132008,1132008,1132008,1202008]:
    date_str =str(i)
    year = date_str[-4:]
    rest = date_str[:-4]
    print(f'year={year} rest= {rest}, all={str(i)}')
    if len(rest)==2:
        month = "0"+rest[0]
        day = "0"+rest[1]
        print(f'year={year} month= {month}, day = {day} all={str(i)}')
        print(datetime.strptime(month+day+year, "%m%d%Y"))
    if len(rest)==3:
        ####assuming that month is the first number i.e. mdd
        ### this can break if say november
        month = '0'+rest[0]
        day = rest[1:3]
        print(f'year={year} month= {month}, day = {day} all={str(i)}')
        print(datetime.strptime(month+day+year, "%m%d%Y"))
```

returns

```
year=2008 month= 01, day = 05 all=152008
2008-01-05 00:00:00
year=2008 month= 01, day = 05 all=152008
2008-01-05 00:00:00
year=2008 month= 01, day = 06 all=162008
2008-01-06 00:00:00
year=2008 month= 01, day = 06 all=162008
2008-01-06 00:00:00
year=2008 month= 01, day = 06 all=162008
2008-01-06 00:00:00
year=2008 month= 01, day = 06 all=162008
2008-01-06 00:00:00
year=2008 month= 01, day = 12 all=1122008
2008-01-12 00:00:00
year=2008 month= 01, day = 12 all=1122008
2008-01-12 00:00:00
year=2008 month= 01, day = 12 all=1122008
2008-01-12 00:00:00
year=2008 month= 01, day = 12 all=1122008
2008-01-12 00:00:00
year=2008 month= 01, day = 13 all=1132008
2008-01-13 00:00:00
year=2008 month= 01, day = 13 all=1132008
2008-01-13 00:00:00
year=2008 month= 01, day = 13 all=1132008
2008-01-13 00:00:00
year=2008 month= 01, day = 13 all=1132008
2008-01-13 00:00:00
year=2008 month= 01, day = 20 all=1202008
2008-01-20 00:00:00
```

Comment: Exception has occurred: ValueError
time data '0112' does not match format '%m%d%Y'

Comment: You don't need the `str` around `month+day+year`.  Those are all strings.

Comment: What about jan 12 and 13?

Comment: Edited it. should be day = rest[1:2]---> day = rest[1:3]